# Set lateinit var to null doesnt work - But in Googles Documentation its in the example

Tags: android, kotlin, admob

So I want to create an interstitial ad in my android application, but their example just does not work (for me?).

They set there the value `mIntersitialAd` to `null`, but its a `lateinit var`, so it should not be possible. Am I missing something there, or is it actually possible?

Link to the Documentation:

[Interstitial Ad](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial-fullscreen#kotlin)

Code example:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAdLoadCallback;

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  
    private lateinit var mInterstitialAd:InterstitialAd
    private final var TAG = 'MainActivity'
  
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
      

      var adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()

      InterstitialAd.load(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest, object : InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
        override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
          Log.d(TAG, adError?.message);
          mInterstitialAd = null
        }

        override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {
          Log.d(TAG, 'Ad was loaded.');
          mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd
        }
      })
        
    }
}
```

And a use of mIntersitialAd:

```
mInterstitialAd.fullScreenContentCallback = object: FullScreenContentCallback() {
  override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
    Log.d(TAG, 'Ad was dismissed.');
  }

  override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError: AdError?) {
    Log.d(TAG, 'Ad failed to show.');
  }

  override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
    Log.d(TAG, 'Ad showed fullscreen content.');
    mInterstitialAd = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: i'm assuming you just wanted to know why they are using lateinit like this, right ? that's the answer i've provided, but if you're looking for an alternative approach to now solving this, let me know and i'll edit my answer, but you'll just remove lateinit and make the variable nullable basically

Comment: Yep, thats what i wanted to know. Either I was not understanding it right or it was really a mistake. @rajan.kali answer also worked to get things going like i wanted to.

Comment: If you can refer to @rajan.kali s answer then I will mark yours as the solution

Comment: i'll refer to what he provided, but it's a joint effort so don't mark anything as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @a_local_nobody mentioned, we cannot but here in this case we can just remove `lateinit`, and make it `nullable` and use the instance with `elvis`

```
private var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd? = null
```

while accessing it just use `?.` , this way you can set it to `null`

```
mInterstitialAd?.fullScreenContentCallback = //...
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a mistake in the documentation, it isn't possible to set that variable equal to null if it's declared with a `lateinit`

```
 private lateinit var foo: String?
```

this  also isn't valid code, because `lateinit` can't be used on nullable variables

docs on lateinit [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables)

> Normally, properties declared as having a non-null type must be
> initialized in the constructor. However, fairly often this is not
> convenient. For example, properties can be initialized through
> dependency injection, or in the setup method of a unit test. In this
> case, you cannot supply a non-null initializer in the constructor, but
> you still want to avoid null checks when referencing the property
> inside the body of a class.
>
> The modifier can be used on var properties declared inside the body of
> a class (not in the primary constructor, and only when the property
> does not have a custom getter or setter) as well as for top-level
> properties and local variables. **The type of the property or variable
> must be non-null, and it must not be a primitive type**.

---

For anyone interested in an alternative solution have a look at the answer provided by @rajan.kali [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66170104/4729721)